# How to increase the priority of POSIX UDP socket receives on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, c, linux, sockets

I'm building a system that opens up a UDP socket on a MacBook Pro, sends out 1024-byte datagrams every 12 mS, and receives said datagrams on an iPhone (I have an iPhone 5). The socket "sends" are happening at the correct period on the macOS side, but the socket "recvs" on the iOS side are getting sporadically delayed by the kernel, sometimes by as much as 200 mS or more! I'm not losing any data (as I do eventually get a flurry of buffered datagrams after the kernel's checked out for awhile), but the intervening delays are unacceptable.

These are audio applications, so I've tried filling some larger receive buffers on the iOS side to account for this kernel behavior. But the delays are cumulative. No matter how big I make my receive buffers, my playback pointer eventually catches up with my write pointer, at which point I play out silence until I have good data again (a successful socket 'recv'). It is very easy to hear when I run out of data, and it happens a lot.

What to do?

Is there any way to increase the priority level of the socket thread so that the kernel doesn't stay out to lunch so long?

Are there any other real-time "fixes" I could employ to improve/avoid this iOS kernel behavior?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure they're getting delayed and it's not just a flaw in the way you're polling for data? If you're getting trashed by 200ms of lag you're asking a lot of the network hardware. Wireless connections can have wildly variable ping times.

Comment: Yes - it's almost certainly not a kernel issue, more likely overall buffering/protocol design/implementation.  As @tadman points out, airside layers are notoriously laggy and, worse, the latency varies widely.  200ms of buffering is nothing.  If your design is not hopelessly bad, and the data still runs out, then you are truly stuft as you have insufficient average bandwidth to do what you wish.

Comment: Sounds like to me here the correct answer is to employ a better buffering scheme. My Netflix, YouTube, and Pandora work just fine on my phone... the video is pulling a lot more data and that's across the internet. Relying on network transfers for real time operations isn't going to end well.

Comment: This: 'my playback pointer eventually catches up with my write pointer' does not fill me with confidence.  Are you queueing buffer instances/pointers/indexes, or actual data?

Comment: Actual data. I issue a non-blocking socket recv inside an audio callback that gets called every 5 mS or so. For the purposes of discussion, I start by queuing up 8 datagrams worth of data, then start playing that data out as I continue to queue up more data every other callback. When the time between successful socket recv calls gets delayed, I can't fill my buffers with good new data. That's when the read pointer catches up to the write pointer.

Comment: You are trying to do this with one thread?

Comment: Yes, the audio callback happens in it's own thread, and I call socket recv from inside that

Comment: @yano - Across the Internet, that would likely be TCP streaming. I'm doing real-time streaming using UDP on a strictly isolated local network, never going out over the 'net.

Comment: my point was pulling down audio/video media over the internet is going to be even slower... TCP is going to add even more overhead and delays... and those applications work just fine with sufficient bandwidth. UDP on your isolated network should blaze compared to the internet. If you can't keep up streaming audio (not much data) then the problem is in the implementation. Perhaps buffer more than 8 datagrams?

Comment: 8 datagrams of buffering that are coming in ever 12 msec is only buffering 100 msec of audio. Do you need that level of sensitivity?

Comment: @yano You cannot compare Netflix, since there is no way (nor need) to detect playout delay.  The receiving application (the Netflix player) can simply increase its in-app receive buffer size when it experiences "starvation," and the viewer would see a pause at that time, but never be aware that playout was delayed thereafter.  However, in Manelion's application any delay is noticeable.  Consider that a delay of more than 50ms is problematic for a two-way phone conversation.

Comment: @bobquinn Fair enough, in hindsight comparing streaming already-existing data to real-time data was poor, but I still don't think simply increasing thread priority is a long term or robust solution, and could lead to system instability.. VoIP isn't going to break for delays >50ms, which I would guess happens quite often.